# Find $P(X+Y>s+t \mid X>s)$ where $X$,$Y$ are independent exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$, $Y$ be independent exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$

I want to find $P(X+Y>s+t \mid X>s)$ where $X$,$Y$ are independent exponential distribution.

My attempt:

\begin{aligned}
P(X+Y>s+t, X>s) &= \int \int \mathbb{1}_{x>s} \mathbb{1}_{x+y>s+t} f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) \,dx\,dy \\&= \int_{s}^{\infty} \int_{s+t-x}^{\infty} f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) \,dx\,dy
\end{aligned}

But I stuck since
\begin{equation}
\int_{s+t-x}^{\infty} f_{Y}(y) \,dy = \int_{s+t-x}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \,dy = e^{-\lambda (s+t-x)}
\end{equation} gives
\begin{equation}
\int_{s}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} e^{-\lambda (s+t-x)} \,dx = \int_{s}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda (s+t)} \,dx = \lambda e^{-\lambda (s+t)}x |_{s}^{\infty} = \infty
\end{equation}

What did I miss?

Comment: For your integrals, note that when $X>s+t$, you're integrating over values $y\in(s+t-X,0)$, i.e. for negative $y$ values. This explains that your integrals yield to high valeus.

Comment: Don't forget that also $f_Y$ has an indicator $1_{y>0}$ so that your formula for the integral $\int_{s+t-x}^\infty \cdots$ only holds for $x<s+t$. I just see that this is the same remark as Václav made 2 minutes before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events $\{X+Y>s+t\}$ and $\{X>s\}$ are not independent. In fact, you can use the memorylessness property of the exponential distribution to conclude that $$P(X+Y>s+t\ |\ X>s)=P(X+Y>t).$$ Now note that $X+Y\sim\Gamma(2,\lambda)$.

Since the probability that the sum of two $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ times is larger then $t$ equals the probability that a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ has at most $1$ jump, your final answer should be $$\exp(-\lambda t)+\lambda t\exp(-\lambda t).$$

Comment: I tried to calculate conditional probability by using definition, so I first do calculation of numerator. What's wrong in my approach? In addition, I know the memory less property of exponential as follows: $P(X>s+t | X>s) = P(X>t)$. How can it be used to prove $P(X+Y>s+t|X>s) = P(X+Y>t)$? I cannot assure since $X+Y$ is gamma, not exponential as you said

Comment: Since you do not have independency, $P(X+Y>s+t,X>s)\neq P(X+Y>s+t)P(X>s)$ in general. To apply the memorylessness property, write $P(X+Y>s+t|X>s)$ as an integral by conditioning on $Y$, then apply memorylessness.

Comment: Thanks. I understand how memorylessness can be applied. On the other hand, eventhough I don't have independency of $X+Y$ and $X$, what's wrong in my equation using indicator function? Since $X$, $Y$ are independent, joint probability of $X$, $Y$ can be factorized. Is there any nonsense in my equation?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the Poisson Process interpretation, see that $P(X+Y>s+t|X>s)=1-P(X+Y\leq s+t|X>s)$

$P(X+Y\leq s+t|X>s)$ is the Probability that there are two arrivals in time $(0,s+t]$ given that there were no arrivals in $[0,s]$ which is just $P(\text{ atleast two arrivals in [s,s+t]})$ due to the Memoryless Property. Now this is just equal to $P(\text{atleast two arrivals in time [0,t]})$ due to the stationary increments property which is just $\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda t)^{j}}{j!}e^{-\lambda t}$

Hence $P(X+Y>s+t|X>s)=1-\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^{j}}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^{1}e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^{j}}{j!}$

$$=e^{-\lambda t}+(\lambda t)e^{-\lambda t}$$

This is because the number of arrivals in time $[0,t]$ is for a Poisson Process of rate $\lambda$ is Poisson Distributed with mean $(\lambda\cdot t)$